# B1/B2 Visa for my kids

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a valid B1/B2 visa which I've used to travel twice to the United States for work. My question is:

I'd love my kids to join me in my next trip, how do I go about their visa application?

Comment: Is there a particular aspect of the application process that concerns you?

Comment: Agreed. You just file the same as if they were adults.

Comment: BTW, You are not allowed to work while on B1/B2 visa.

Comment: @ISAE I guess the OP meant the travel was for business.

Comment: If someone at immigration will ever connect this post to actual person, you might be banned from entering USA. If you meant "Consult with business associates, Attend a scientific, educational, professional, or business convention or conference, Settle an estate, Negotiate a contract", please edit to make it clear you did not, in fact, violated your visa rules.